# Intersection coordinates change when I change values for domain

Tags: coordinates, intersections, domain

I'm trying to plot a function using Tikz/Pgfplots. Am still new to using Tikz/Pgfplots. I've created the code using various sources. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document} 

  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\scriptsize
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=0, xmax=525,
      ymin=-2.25, ymax=1.75,
      xtick={0,25,...,500},
      ytick={-2,-1.5,...,1.5},
      axis lines=middle,
      ymajorgrids,
      tick label style={font=\tiny},
      xlabel near ticks,
      ylabel near ticks,
      label style={font=\scriptsize},
      y axis line style={stealth-stealth},
      xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
      xticklabel style={rotate=90},
      x axis line style={name path=xaxis},
      ]
      \addplot[name path=s,blue,very thick,domain=0:300] {-1.6 + 10/(1+\x/100)^1 - 10/(1+\x/100)^2};
    
      \fill[red,name intersections={of=s and xaxis,name=i},] (i-1) circle (2pt);
    
      \draw[font=\tiny,name intersections={of=s and xaxis},] node[pin={right:\pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(i-1)} (\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{ \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}}\%, \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{ \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}})}] at (i-1){};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This generates the following plot:
[image: Correct intersection coordinates]

The coordinates of the intersection point is correct (25%,0). However, when I change the domain to `domain=0:500`, the coordinates of the intersection point changes to (26.39%,0), which is wrong. Here's the plot with the changed domain:

[image: Wrong intersection coordinates]

Any ideas on why this is happening? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Guess: You have the same number of points, and that implies that there is a longer distance between the sampling points (one can almost see that). The value you get is where the broken line intersects. Maybe you are better off by increasing the number of sampling points?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That along with @Zarko's reworking of the code helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in your example `xaxis` and `s` have not at any sample point the same value, so intersections actually happens somewhere between sample points.

To see this, just remove option `\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{...}` from printing coordinate of the intersection points.

Of course, if you increase number of samples (from the default value) as suggested  @mickep in his comment, difference between coordinates at different domain size will become smaller. For example at ˙samples=101` difference is almost neglecting small:

[image]

and

[image]

MWE, with a bit modified/shortened code for demonstrating this, is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[
C/.style = {circle, draw=none, fill=red, inner sep=2pt, node contents={},
            pin=above right:{\pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(#1)} %
    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}\%,
     \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y})
                            }
            }
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    y axis line style={stealth-stealth},
    x axis line style={name path=xaxis},
    ymajorgrids,
%
    xmin=0,     xmax=525,
    ymin=-1.75, ymax=1.75,
    xtick={0,25,...,500},
    ytick={-1.5,...,1.5},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
    xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
    xticklabel style={rotate=90},
%
    no marks,
    domain=0:300,
    %  domain=0:500,
    samples=101     % <---
      ]
\addplot +[name path=s,
           very thick]  {-1.6 + 10/(1+\x/100)^1 - 10/(1+\x/100)^2};

\fill[red,name intersections={of=s and xaxis,name=i}] (i-1)  node[C={i-1}];
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Zarko. That works. Appreciate the reworked code.